# NTFS permissions with multiple user groups

Tags: windows, file-permissions, ntfs

I do not know how to search for this, so I am sorry if this has already been asked.
Also, I am new to Windows administration so if I say something wrong do not hesitate to correct me!

I have a folder structure that looks like this:

```
shared\
 +- project1\
 |   +- departmentA\
 |   +- departmentB\
 +- project2\
     +- departmentA\
     +- departmentB\
```

I need that users in department A assigned to project 1 can access **only** `shared\Project1\DepartmentA`. How can I achieve this?

If this question is too broad, please feel free to redirect me to the relevant documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Just set your permission accordingly. I would create two groups (DepartmentA and DepartmentB) and assign appropiate rights for both on `\shared`, then disable inheritance on the department folders and re-assign the groups as necessary.

Comment: I might be missing something, but how would I set permissions so that a person from department A who is assigned ONLY to project 1 cannot access `shared\Project1\DepartmentA`?

Comment: Allow Access to project1, deny access to project2?

Comment: Ok let me be sure I understood. I should do as many user groups as departments and give access to the scattered departments folders to these groups. Then I should set the permissions on projects folders to the users cleared to access the projects. Have I got this right?

Comment: Yes, you will have to create as many different ressource- (security) groups as you have ressources to give granular access to. Instead of creating secrity groups, you could add every user to every ressource acl, but in most caeses roups are a lot easier to manage.